# Remove URLs from a text file

Tags: regex, python-3.x, url

I need to remove all the urls from a text file. I read the file, I iterate line by line and I write a clean file. however the below code acting weird. It removes the first line of the original file and add new 3 lines in total. Most important it doesn't remove the urls.

```
import sys
import re

sys.stdout = open('text_clean.txt', 'w')

with open("text.txt",encoding="'Latin-1'") as f:
    rep = re.compile(r"""
                        http[s]?://.*?\s
                        |www.*?\s
                        |(\n)
                        """, re.X)
    non_asc = re.compile(r"[^\x00-\x7F]")
    for line in f:
        non = non_asc.search(line)
        if non:
            continue
        m = rep.search(line)
        if m:
            line = line.replace(m.group(), "")
            if line.strip():
                print(line.strip())
```

Comment: why do you overwrite stdout ? you don't need that

Answer (score 1):

You can replace any match with "" with regex, and it's probably the most efficient way to do it

```
import re
new_file = open('text_clean.txt', 'w')
with open("text.txt",encoding="'Latin-1'") as f:
    text = re.sub(r'(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?([-a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4})\b(?:\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?',"",f.read(),flags=re.MULTILINE)
    text = '\n'.join([a for a in text.split("\n") if a.strip()])
    new_file.write(text)

new_file.close()
```

Test example I used :

```
asdas
d
asd
asd
https://www.google.com
http://facebook.com
facebook.com
google.com
dasd.asdasd.asd //this is url too ?
```

Output:

```
asdas
d
asd
asd
 //this is url too ?
```

Comment: It does exactly what the previous one did. It removes the 1st line, it adds 2 lines at the total number of lines in text file and it does not remove any http any URL.

Comment: can you give us example of input file

Comment: it works for part of the file, then I get a UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec. I have tried encode ASCII and UTF-8 with no joy. I have paste a text example here http://pastebin.com/brShh2DT

Comment: please can you advise on this?

Comment: I have the issue when try to write the new text file. I am not sure if I can fix with the str.translate() method.

Comment: @ganesa75: I used `open("text_to_be_clean.txt", encoding="utf8")` and it seemed to work on a downloaded copy of your [pastebin text file](http://pastebin.com/brShh2DT).

Comment: I got the same error instead: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
on new_file.write(text) 
so, no when I open the file to clean but when I create the new file. 
I am not sure if is "non_ascii" stuff that cause the issue